# How to create even cell spacing within a <table>

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have been working on a small. However, I have a table where the cells are all sized automatically by the size of the text in each cell. How would I go about making all the cells the same width? For example, have 10 cells across, with each cell always using up 10% of the table's width.

You can see an JSFiddle of a table where the cells are different widths depending on the text here: https://jsfiddle.net/0sLb8cyo/2/

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry buddy. Let me try and post an example

Comment: You set table to block then unset ... ?? table-layout:fixed; should do with a table set to display:table; (with or without a width) to even column's width

Comment: Here is a link to see table-layout:fixed + :empty + flex update of your CSS in action setting your  3tables side by side with out/less gaps :) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWjxEwY **or your fiddle i just saw : https://jsfiddle.net/u3gko9ax/ .**

Answer (score -1):

Insert this into the CSS and you will succeed

```
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table td {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
table td {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>boat</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
    <td>car</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The hard-coded `2%` are not really responsive-proof.